# Repeated measures in a mixed model

Tags: regression, mixed-model, predictive-models, modeling

I'm trying to fit a mixed model for data from different medical centers, where "center" is thought of as random. I have data over 2 years on how many patients they receive each day. I have several measures which are related to the centers. Some are repeated observations, but some change between each observation. For example, for each center I have the number of registered patients, which doesn't change across the 2 years for each center (the measurement was taken at one point in time). But then I have measures which change for each day, such as the number of doctors working on that day. I have created this initial model:

```
Model <- lmer(PatientsReceieved ~ NumberOfDoctors + (1 | Centers), data = train)
```

How do I add the measures which are repeated across all the days, but are different for each center (like the number of registered patients one above)?

Do  I need to treat them differently from the observations which change each day?

Comment: Just for reference: Variables that change over time in a longitudinal model are called "time-varying covariates" or "time-dependent covariates" whereas variables that stay the same are called "time-invariant". There are probably more terms but these are the most frequent I encountered. To my knowledge, they are not treated differently in the model (syntax) itself, just the interpretation of the results differs between them.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of notes:

- You should more carefully think about the nature of your outcome data that will dictate what type of model to use. For example, the outcome patients_received sounds as a count outcome, and therefore you may want to consider a mixed model for count data (e.g., Poisson or negative binomial). In case you will treat the outcome as a count think also about including an offset term for the length of the period the data have been collected in each center.
- The type of covariates that you will be able to include will depend on the level at which you aggregate the data. For example, will you use the patients_received per day or per month. In the former case it would be possible to include also covariates that change per day, but not in the latter.